# Send data using wlan in cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, wifi

I want to develop an ionic app that can send receive data using wlan to other devices connected to the same network without internet. Is there any plugin or method available in cordova to send/receive data in local networks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket

I have included it in two of my apps to exchange data between devices in the same network via sockets. I use it also to implement a local webserver on the devices.

It works on iOS and Android, the API docs you find here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket

And here you find same samples: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/

Comment: Is there any implementation anywhere? The google chrome examples show communication using TcpServer, which is not available in this cordova plugin. I understand that there is a possibility of communication between only clients? Maybe you know another way at the moment?