# Send JSON data between two android or Ipad devices offline (bluetooth) Ionic Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth, ionic-framework

I want to develop an ionic app that can send receive data using wlan or Bluetooth to other devices connected to the same network without internet. Is there any plugin or method available in cordova to send/receive data in local networks.

I tried given answer in this link,
[Send data using wlan in cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241018/send-data-using-wlan-in-cordova-app/34245338#34245338)

But i could not send JSON data. I could not find exact example i need. Please guide me with best example.

Comment: Have you started to write a server/client as I wrote/linked in my answer? Or do you just have the problem, that you don't know how to send JSON data?

Comment: @joerg Sorry for late reply. I am using Socket connection using TCP cordova plugin. I can able to compile and run the code in two android devices. It has Data, addr and port with Send button . Both devices are connected in same network. When i click send button , I'm not receiving data in other devices. Its connected successfully but not receiving data.

Please help me out with any example code. Have i done anything wrong ?

Comment: Moreover the above plugin is for tcp client. Can i have plugin for tcp server ?